# yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss to ddmmyy in SQL Server procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to convert `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss` to `ddmmyy` in a SQL Server stored procedure, but can't do it. Can someone sort this thing out?

and also need (27-Apr-18) in this format also ?

Comment: Try to use `FORMAT` - `SELECT FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(),'MMddyy')` (it's starting with SQLServer 2012)

Comment: Why? It's likely that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how data types work.

Comment: I've updated my answer according to the desired result format.

Comment: @Manu C Rajan I edited my answer Try my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss'), 'ddMMyy')
```

**OR**

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME,column_name), 'ddMMyy')
```

**Example:**

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME,'2018-04-26 10:20:12.222'), 'ddMMyy')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
260418
```

**Demo:**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4d22b/36

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Once you have your value as a `Date` data type, to get to `dd-MMM-yy` format you can also use a combination of `convert` and `replace`:

```
DECLARE @Date as datetime = GETDATE();

SELECT  @Date As Original, 
        REPLACE(CONVERT(char(9), @Date, 6), ' ', '-') As Result
```

Will return:

```
Original                Result
01.05.2018 08:08:29     01-May-18
```

**Note:** I've updated my answer due to the desired result format change from `mmddyyy` to `ddmmyy` - All I've changed was the convert style - from 1 to 3.

**Original answer**

If your original value is of type `DateTime` it has no display value. All you need to use is [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DECLARE @Date as datetime = GETDATE();

SELECT  @Date As Original, 
        REPLACE(CONVERT(char(8), @Date, 3), '/', '') As Result

Original                Result
26.04.2018 06:56:19     042618
```

If your original value is a string type, you first convert it to `datetime` and then convert back to a string with the desired display format:

```
DECLARE @StringDate as char(23) = '2018-04-26 07:55:43.003'

SELECT @StringDate As Original,  
       REPLACE(CONVERT(char(8), CONVERT(datetime, @StringDate, 120), 3), '/', '') As Result

Original                    Result
2018-04-26 07:55:43.003     042618
```

In Sql Server 2012 or higher you can use `Format` to convert the `datetime` to whatever string representation you want, but `Format` is slower than `convert` and `replace`, so if you are using it on a large table, you should consider using the good old `convert` instead.
For more information, read Aaron Bertrand's [FORMAT() is nice and all, but…](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CreatedOn,10),'-','')
```

In this above line `CreatedOn` is the column name.

Comment: `101` returns 4 digit year, and you need to get rid of the `)` after the `CreatedOn`.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'ddMMyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

OrderDate is variable.

concat(month(OrderDate),DAY(OrderDate),right(YEAR(OrderDate),2))as date