# Convert '2018-07-02 00:01:22.000' to '02-Jul-18' in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time, sql-server-2012

I amm trying to convert `'2018-07-02 00:01:22.000'` to `'02-Jul-18'` in SQL Server.  I have tried the below possibilities using the basic SQL Server `CONVERT()` function, but I can't get the solution.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(11), transfer_date, 106) 

DECLARE @Date AS DateTime = '2018-07-02 00:01:22.000'
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(12), @Date, 106)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: select convert(varchar(11), transfer_date, 106)

Comment: did you know `cast()`

Comment: is it not to convert from one data type to another? am a beginner in SQL, sorry if am wrong.

Comment: In future please _edit_ the question and add what you tried. Even better, actually put it in there in the first place.

Comment: what about this `SELECT FORMAT( GETDATE(), 'dd-MMM-yyyy');`  in SSMS'14

Comment: Possible duplicate of [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss to ddmmyy in SQL Server procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50034953/yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-sss-to-ddmmyy-in-sql-server-procedures)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert the *string* `'2018-07-02 00:01:22.000'` to the *string* `'02-Jul-18'`, then you'll have to use `CONVERT` twice, once to bring the input to a date, and a second time, to bring that date back to a string in the format you want.

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,
                    CONVERT(datetime, '2018-07-02 00:01:22.000', 121),
                    106), ' ' , '-');
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that if you starting value is already date time, you may do away with one of the calls to `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, transfer_date, 106), ' ' , '-');
```

Answer (score 1):

The query below will help to return the DateTime in to `DD-Mon-YY` format:

```
DECLARE @Date AS DateTime = '2018-07-02 00:01:22.000';
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), @Date, 6), ' ', '-');
```

Result:

```
02-Jul-18
```

Comment: Thanks, Arul Kumar. It's simple and perfect.

Comment: This is excellent. I didn't know about the option 6 that uses `YY` instead of `YYYY`. Just read the docs to realize that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017. The more you know! Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try below line of code :

```
declare @Date as DateTime='2018-07-02 00:01:22.000'

select REPLACE(Convert(varchar(12),@Date,106),' ','-')
```

Comment: need a '-' in between these '02 Jul 2018' like these  - "02-Jul-18"

Comment: It is very simple thing select REPLACE(Convert(varchar(12),@Date,106),' ','-')

Comment: use `replace(@date,' ','-')`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
declare @mydate datetime2
declare @converted varchar(100)
set @mydate = cast('2018-07-02 00:01:22.000' as datetime2)
set @converted = replace(convert(varchar, @mydate , 106), ' ', '-')                    

select concat(left(@converted, 7), right(@converted, 2))
```

Example: http://rextester.com/BCAZ47264

Result: `02-Jul-18`

**One statement query**

```
select 
concat(
    left (
        replace (
            convert(varchar, cast('2018-07-02 00:01:22.000' as datetime2), 106),
            ' ',
            '-'
        ), 7)
    , right (
        replace (
            convert(varchar, cast('2018-07-02 00:01:22.000' as datetime2), 106),
            ' ',
            '-'
        ), 2)
    )
```

Comment: It's Working Fine Dude @zedfoxus. Thanks all for this thread. If Found anything better than this feel free to post.

Comment: Great. Mark any of the answers provided to your question as a final answer to give closure to your question.

Comment: You are using lots of functions. That's function abuse. Cast, Convert, Replace, Left, right and concat. you can achieve the same with Convert and Replace.